# Local Notifications plugin is working inconsistently

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, localnotification

Trying to trigger a notification every day at a specific time, but Its works for only 1/2 days. Please let me know, how to fix this issue.

My Code :

```
this.localNotifications.schedule({      
  id:  1,      
  title: 'App name',      
  text: 'Quiz Start...',      
  trigger: { every: { hour: 9, minute: 0 }, count: 1000 },     
  sound: 'default',      
  priority: 1,      
  foreground: true,      
  sticky: true
})
```